# Add an image to a JList item

Tags: java

I have a JList and i am using DefaultListModel,everything is well and the items(strings)are added correctly, but i want to add an image in JList beside each string (e.g.to show the status of the users).Can anyone help me about that? Thanks in advance.Here is how i add the elements,can i add images too?

```
private  DefaultListModel modelO = (DefaultListModel) Teacher.made_list.getModel();
((DefaultListModel) Teacher.made_list.getModel()).addElement(studName);
```

Comment: Accept an answer so that people can know which solution solved your problem.

Comment: Accept the answer, please! Mark the `V` at the left side of the question and it will become green meaning this was the solution that worked for you. If you're not fully satisfied with the answers, please post a comment on it saying what is missing to become acceptable by you.

Answer (score 7):

You have to implement [ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) (or extend [DefaultListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html)) and have the `getListCellRendererComponent` method to return a `Jlabel` with an icon in it.

Example:

```
public class IconListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        Icon icon = this.getIcon(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus)
        label.setIcon(icon);
        return label;
    }
    protected Icon getIcon(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        // how do I get icon?
    }
}
```

You have to implement the `getIcon` method.

Answer (score 3):

The model is used to store the data, and a renderer is used to display the data.  The default renderer can handle Strings and icons but if you need to do more than that, you can provide a custom renderer.  Here is an [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer).  It's for a combo box, but the renderer is the same for JLists.

Comment: +1 for the link to the Swing tutorial. Tt helps solve this problem and the tutorial can be used as a resource for future questions.

Comment: @Fatema Mohsen you are welcome :) but you don't really need to thank us, just an upvote and marking one of the answers correct will make everyone happy.

Comment: To clarify, "default renderer can handle Strings and icons" means that it can handle *either* a string or an icon but not both at the same time. At least that is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find complex solution including

- Custom JList elements (that allows to get icon image from list element)
- Handling selection styling
- More convinient way of using ListCellRenderer than just extending Default

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jlist-custom-renderer-example