# Adding a Icon to JList Item

Tags: java, swing, jlist, imageicon, renderer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java:Add an image to a JList item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807463/javaadd-an-image-to-a-jlist-item)

```
public class ClientUserPanel extends JPanel {

    private JList userlist;
    private JScrollPane scrollist;
    private DefaultListModel listmodel;

    public ClientUserPanel() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setSize(100, 200);
        listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
        userlist = new JList(listmodel);
        scrollist = new JScrollPane(userlist);
        listmodel.addElement("uday");
        listmodel.addElement("ravi");
        listmodel.addElement("uday");
        this.add(scrollist, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Here I have a JList and i had added items to the list and its working correctly, but i want to add an icon in JList beside each item .
for example to show the status of user,either he was offline or online.
can any one please help me

Comment: Refer to,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807463/javaadd-an-image-to-a-jlist-item

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html).  This will allow you to define how each element should be painted.  You can also refer to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples of how to achieve it.

Comment: Good answer to a duplicate question, but please consider linking to the latest (v. 7) JavaDocs in future.

Comment: Not every one's using Java 7 ;), but I personally have no issues

Comment: (shrugs) I'm coding for v. 6 at the moment, but *always* use the latest JavaDocs.  That way, I can get a 'heads up' on methods, attributes or classes that might be deprecated in Java 7.  If the replacement is not available in Java 6, I'll add a TODO flag to the (soon to be) deprecated code.  I feel it is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875). Please vote for the RFE.  I raised the RFE - so yes, this is something I **have** thought about.  ;)